# How do you pronounce "Hartshorne"?

Tags: terminology

What is the "correct" pronunciation of Robin Hartshorne's last name? Mostly I hear it pronounced "Har-shorn" although I've also heard "Harts-orn" and maybe a few other variations.

Comment: Sorry, I think this is off-topic, so I'm voting to close (but I basically agree with Will's answer).

Comment: Here are two similar questions, to which we might want to apply the same standards: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/4381/pronunciation-dijkstra, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/4394/pronunciation-crapo

Comment: Fair enough.  I guess we have a "names" tag for a reason.

Comment: I pity the poor devils with unpronounceable names...

Comment: I'm with Georges on this.

Comment: I was once told, "'Hart-shorn' is the book, 'Harts-horn' is the person."

Comment: The poor devils could follow Kiran Kedlaya's example: http://www.mit.edu/~kedlaya/about-my-name.html

Answer (score 28, accepted):

He prefers it be pronounced as in Hart's  Horn. I asked him a few years ago, our brief common ground being assisting Marvin Jay Greenberg with revisions for the fourth edition of his book on Euclidean and non-Euclidean geometry. That is not to say that I have ever heard anyone else say it that way. But then few people get my name right.

Comment: How is Jagy pronounced?

Comment: Thank you, kind sir. It is J as in judge, long a, hard g as in gorilla, y to rhyme with e, all as common in American English. That being said, the name is
 most likely from Switzerland or Alsace-Lorraine by way of Ellis Island, no reliable way of knowing

Comment: Wow, I assumed your name was Hungarian (like Nagy), which would give a completely different pronunciation.

Comment: As it happens, I asked Robin the same qustion a few weeks ago and he replied: "think of hart's horn (it means the horn of a deer)"

Comment: I had also assumed "Jagy" was Hungarian. (For the record, "Lugo" is Spanish, and pronounced as such.) 

Comment: More precisely, 'Lugo' is Galician! :)


Comment: (So is Figueroa, by the way.)


Comment: In Europe most of the people do pronounce harts-horn. I was using this in US as well and spoiled it a bit more recently after being contaminated by the prononciation of some colleagues. So more recently I said it few times Harts-shorn what is likely wrong. In any case I am surprise that you say that you hear nobody around Berkeley saying it harts-horn. 

Comment: I'm sure people who have regular contact with him have figured it out.

Comment: BTW, my given name is Robert Lewis; people call me Bob Lewis. That's "B" as in Banach, "o" as in "operator", "L" as in "Labochevsky", an "ew" diphthong pronounced generally as the "u" in "grand *U*-nified theory, "i" as in "integral" and "s" as in "simplex". Any questions?

Comment: To reaffirm what Zoran said, I have never heard somebody in Poland or Germany pronouncing it Hart-shorn.

Comment: I am German and I have the impression that people in Germany usually pronounce it Hart-shorn.

Comment: I once heard somebody quip that the man's name is pronounced "Hart's Horn" but the book is pronounced "Hart Shorn."